# hibernate would not able to save object sequentially in DB

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

There are 3 user logged in a application ,say A,B,C. I had implemented a business logic if  user A save a Object(using hibernate)in DB (say Employee object) for other it will mark as "duplicate" processing state in Employee table (every records  have a Processing State like success, error, duplicate). I put the code block in which employee object is persisted in synchronization block. But my problem is “when  all 3 user click on save employee button at same time ,3 object are save in DB, the code in synchronization block are executing  serially for all 3 user but  it save object in DB at same time due to that I am not able to mark the record as duplicate (before save the object I have a check of processing state)”. I want to save object one  by one means if all 3 are click on save Employee button same time, the thread which enter first in synchronization block  the should save the employee object 1st so that I can mark the records  duplicate for other.

I have implemented  code as below

```
synchronized(this){
   find processing state of each records.
   if record is have success status mark as duplicate
   else save the object in DB with status proccesing (by using hibernate)
   save function is {
            session().save(object) (hibernate session )
            session().flush();
      }
   // do some other work 

  update the records status success
}// close the synchronized block
```

If 1st user save records  successfully. But I am not able to get records status  “success for other use”

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Are you committing the transaction inside your synchronized block or out side??

Comment: committing the transaction inside the synchronized block and again same records updated out side the block.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the status to 'Success' after you have saved the object. Due to this the status in not persisted.

You need to set the status 'Success' on the object and then save it.